# aspnet_regiis saying success but connectionString section unchanged

Tags: web-config, aspnet-regiis.exe

So I have a web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="AS400" providerName="System.Data.ProviderName" connectionString="DataSource=REDACTED; UserID=REDACTED; Password=REDACTED; InitialCatalog=REDACTED; DataCompression=True; CheckConnectionOnOpen=True; CharBitDataAsString=True; Naming = System" />
  </connectionStrings>
...
```

And I'm trying to figure out how to encrypt the connectionStrings section, following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100)).

I navigated to the location of the published web app and ran the following command as an admin: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app / -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"`

The command output the following:

> Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.0
> Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
> Encrypting configuration section...
> Succeeded!

...But it didn't seem to *do* anything! The web.config is unchanged.

I'm probably missing something obvious here but I've never used aspnet_regiis before so I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Running it with an app of \ in the correct location isn't good enough. (Likewise, for some reason, navigating to just C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 then running aspnet_regiis doesn't work). Need to fully-qualify both paths:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "C:\Atlassian\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\4587526-3997713"`